# How to glide back to the top of the browser window using Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I click a button I want the glide back up to the top of the window. I know you can use window.scrollTo(0,0) but that just jumps straight to the top. I want to have that easy glide feature.
Would very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
 window.scrollTo({ top: 200, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```js
document.querySelector("#scrolltop").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  document.body.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});
```

```css
#scrolltop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores labore dicta, officiis repudiandae rem, et inventore voluptate optio. Dolorum molestias vero autem sapiente, totam architecto est dicta, voluptatem corporis voluptas.</p>

<button type="button" id="scrolltop">Go top</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `behavior: smooth` to achieve it:

```
window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
})
```